# hi Ii have added a background to the game using a different method

Tags: swift, swift-playground, generics

the game is similar to flap bird but i want to make it in my own way. the background i have used a image of Sky. however i don't understand how the overlaying is actually functioning. Every image can be seen individually. However when i try to start the game with all the images together it doesn't show the bird or the trees. can anyone guide me on the same.thanks

```
    /* Setup your scene here */
    //Physics

    bird = SKSpriteNode(texture: BirdTexture)
    bird.setScale(0.5)
    bird.position = CGPoint (x: self.frame.size.width * 0.35, y: self.frame.size.height * 0.6)
    bird.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: bird.size.height/2.0)


    //background is set here
    var backgroundTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "background.png")
    var sprite1 = SKSpriteNode(texture: backgroundTexture)
    sprite1.setScale(2.0)
    sprite1.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width/2.0, y: self.size.height/2.0)
    self.addChild(sprite1)
    var background = SKNode()
    background.position = CGPointMake(0, backgroundTexture.size().height)
    background.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width, backgroundTexture.size().height * 2.0))
    background.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
    self.addChild(background)


    //ground is set here similar to the background.

   //tree set here
    let pipeDown = SKSpriteNode (texture: pipeDownTexture)
    pipeDown.setScale(2.0)
    pipeDown.position = CGPointMake(100.0 , CGFloat(y) + pipeDown.size.height + CGFloat(pipeGap))
    pipeDown.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody (rectangleOfSize: pipeDown.size)
    pipeDown.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
    pipePair.addChild(pipeDown)

    //pipe Up is set similarly




    pipePair.runAction(PipesMoveAndRemove)
    self.addChild(pipePair)

}
```

i have changed the way you add a background to the game however after doing that i can't see the bird nor the tree(pipes). How do i get it up.????

Comment: Show the relevant bits, not an entire page-worth of code. Please.

Answer (score 0):

I saw quickly your code here and I found some thing to you test.

Look when you add your children in Scene, **first you add Bird** and after you add your background.

Remember the layout when will build it work like layer, if you add first your bird and after the background, so your background is in front of bird.

```
var BirdTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed:"Bird")
BirdTexture.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringMode.Nearest
bird = SKSpriteNode(texture: BirdTexture)
bird.setScale(0.5)
bird.position = CGPoint (x: self.frame.size.width * 0.35, y: self.frame.size.height * 0.6)
bird.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: bird.size.height/2.0)
bird.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
bird.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false

//background is set here
var backgroundTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "background.png")
var sprite1 = SKSpriteNode(texture: backgroundTexture)
sprite1.setScale(2.0)
sprite1.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width/2.0, y: self.size.height/2.0)
self.addChild(sprite1)
var background = SKNode()
background.position = CGPointMake(0, backgroundTexture.size().height)
background.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width, backgroundTexture.size().height * 2.0))
background.physicsBody?.dynamic = true



//ground is set here
var groundTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed:"ground")
var sprite = SKSpriteNode(texture: groundTexture)
sprite.setScale(2.0)
sprite.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width/2.0, y: self.size.height/7.0)
self.addChild(sprite)
        var ground = SKNode()
ground.position = CGPointMake(0, groundTexture.size().height)
ground.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width, groundTexture.size().height * 2.0))

ground.physicsBody?.dynamic = true

//I removed your sequence and put here
self.addChild(background)
self.addChild(ground)
self.addChild(bird)
```

Sorry, I don't check the code with xcode, I just imagine the solution, try it.